# SQL Server Reporting - Credentials

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have been working on SQL Server Reporting Services 2008, and i am connecting to report server from asp.net using below code:

```
ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService();
                System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials.Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"].ToString();
                System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"].ToString();
                System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString();
                rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;


                // Render arguments
                byte[] result = null;
                string reportpath = reportPath;
                string format = "PDF";
                string historyID = null;
                string devInfo = @"<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>";

                string encoding;
                string mimeType;
                string extension;
                ParameterValue[] parameters = new ParameterValue[1];
                parameters[0] = new ParameterValue();
                parameters[0].Name = reportParameterBidName.Trim();
                parameters[0].Value = reportParameterBidValue.Trim();
                Warning[] warnings = null;

                string[] streamIDs = null;

                ExecutionInfo execInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
                ExecutionHeader execHeader = new ExecutionHeader();

                rs.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader;

                execInfo = rs.LoadReport(reportpath, historyID);
                rs.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-us");



                String SessionId = rs.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID;

                try
                {
                    result = rs.Render(format, devInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);
                    return result;
                }
                catch (SoapException e)
                {
                    return null;
                }
```

Now it works well with my local server, when i upload it to final server it does not work and throws unable to connect error. If i use VPN and use same credentials then too it is working.

Please advise on this.

Comment: Is it a connect error or an authentication error? Is it even able find/ping the server?

Comment: Yes it is able to ping, then too it is giving unable to connect to the server error

Comment: Is there any more detail to the error? Could you post it?